# Using IFTTT web hook with values; values doesn't get through

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, ifttt

I am running the following Javascript code:

```js
const httpPost = (title, msg, trigger, key) => {
    const URL = `https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/${trigger}/with/key/${key}`
    const data = {
        value1: title,
        value2: msg
    }
    fetch(URL, {
        data: data,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        method: "POST"
    }).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
}
```

The web hook got triggered. However, the values are not provided.

When I check `https://ifttt.com/activity/applet/...` I can see it was triggered and the values are empty.

Even when I `JSON.stringify()` the data the value fields are still empty. What am I doing wrong?

Instead of `data` I also tried `body` or `payload` as options. The results didn't change.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're posting the body encoded in JSON format, you should use a different Maker URL. Instead of what you have try [https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{event}/json/with/key/{key}](https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/%7Bevent%7D/json/with/key/%7Bkey%7D). The URL that you're sending to is for form encoded data.

See this Help Center article on IFTTT: https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405029291163-Parsing-JSON-body-with-filter-code